# can ffmpeg use actual frame number in stream instead of sequentially added image numbers

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg  -i test.mp4  -vf select="eq(pict_type\,I)"  %d.png
```

above code create file name incremental by 1, like:

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
...
```

but I want the actual frame number in the source stream:

```
1.png
26.png
51.png
...
```

there is very [old thread](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-January/012837.html) asking the same thing. But I wonder is there a solution right now?

Comment: imho, because, frames doesn't have frame number info: `ffprobe -f lavfi movie=input.mp4,select='eq(pict_type\,I)' -show_frames`